# Is there an Easy Way to Add Fonts?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, fonts, fontconfig

After losing my beloved 5+ year Gentoo install to a hardware failure, I've gone to FreeBSD.  I felt this was the next logical step in my exploration and use of source based operating systems.  In reading all the [associated documentation for FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/), while installing the XOrg Server, the [5.6 - Using Fonts in XOrg section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-fonts.html) caught my attention.  Having realized I never added the line:

```
Section "Files"
   FontPath  "/usr/share/fonts/...."
EndSection
```

for any fonts on my Gentoo install, I now understand why my DE looked like crap.  Being a disabled one handed typist makes it tougher on me to edit the `Files Section` by hand, and I would prefer to add fonts by hand as a last resort.  As such, is there a way to add the output from `fc-list : file` to the Files Section of `xorg.conf` using either a tool someone created that I have yet to find, or some fancy shell script etc that the readers here are so good at crafting?

**Note**: I use `nvidia-xconfig` to generate my `xorg.conf` file, so it's far from the modular approach recommended nowadays.  Can I mix and match the conf.d approach with the generated config if need be?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question, and you have vim installed on the system (this could work with `vi` as well, as these are just `ex` commands)
Running the below command at a terminal, will:

- read in the file: `xorg.conf` - obviously replace this with the file you want to modify. Note: this file `xorg.conf` will **not** be modified, in case something goes wrong with the script.
- do some text manipulation
- the output of the commands will be place in file: `/tmp/temp_xorg.conf`

If after these operations, you are satisfied with the state of `/tmp/temp_xorg.conf` you could copy it to the location of your real, working xorg config file.

---

#### run the commands

run this at a shell prompt to produce fontpaths directories which are in a format that can go in an xorg conf file (thanks to @meuh for this command).

```
fc-list : file | sed -E 's#(.*)/.*#\tFontPath "\1"#' | sort -u > /tmp/filepaths.txt
```

then run this command, which will take the output of the above command and insert it into the "Files" sections

```
$ vim -e xorg.conf << 'EOF' 
" move cursor to the line with the text: `Section "Files"`
/Section "Files"
" read in the output of `fc-list` at this point
r !fc-list
write /tmp/temp_xorg.conf
EOF
```

so if for example, `xorg.conf` looked like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection
```

After running the above command `/tmp/temp_xorg.conf` should look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath "/home/ubuntu/.fonts"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/opentype/stix-word"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-guru-extra"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst-one"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lao"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lohit-punjabi"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/nanum"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/padauk"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/sinhala"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/takao-gothic"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tibetan-machine"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-khmeros-core"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts"
    FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection
```

Comment: That's very close... Every Directory entry needs a `FontPath`. See [FreeBSD fonts](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-fonts.html)

Comment: @eyoung100 and the path needs to be wrapped in quotes and indented too,  right?

Comment: @eyoung100 , I cant get the above command to fix up all the inserted lines programmatically, but on my instance of `vim` visually selecting all the inserted lines and running this on the command line worked `:'<,'>normal! I^IFontPath "^[A"^[j` note: in this case `^I` is a real `<TAB>` character, and `^[` is a real `<Escape>` character, Im not sure if they will be preserved through this web interface. But, for some reason, that command wont work when running vim in the non-interactive ex mode (thats what `vim -e` does)

Comment: I'll try this shortly... trying to install DE now and running into a hurdle... Oh ad the font names don't need to be there, only one occurence of each fonts directory

Comment: @eyoung100 oh ok, do you know how to get `fc-list` to only output the folder name, without the fonts?, I tried using the command in your description `fc-list :file`  but it did the same thing as `fc-list`

Comment: You need a space after the ":". This should get you a list of suitable lines: `fc-list : file | sed 's|\(.*\)/.*| FontPath "\1"|' | sort -u`

Comment: @eyoung100 ok, thanks to meuh for getting the fontpath formatting, I think this might be close to what you were wanting?

Answer (score 1):

For the configuration "mix and match" part of the question - the answer is "kind of".

The `xorg.conf` man page lists the configuration sources in order of precedence, and states "When the same information is supplied in more than one way, the highest precedence mechanism is used".

By observation (since "same information" and "more than one way" aren't clearly defined in the man page, to my mind), this means you cannot override/update a section in `xorg.conf` (like `Section "Files"` for fonts) with an `xorg.conf.d` file since that has lower precedence. Although lower precedence files are read and parsed, section contents are silently disregarded for those sections that already exist at a higher precedence.

The current Nvidia driver (396, on Linux only) *does* now use an `xorg.conf.d` fragment, but only for the Linux DRM Xorg driver, it still creates a near-monolithic `xorg.conf` during installation.

Happily, `nvidia-xconfig` does not change this section, so if it helps you could comment it out of `xorg.conf` and migrate it into one or more `xorg.conf.d` files. Multiple duplicate sections at the same precedence, i.e. all within a single `xorg.conf.d` directory, *does* result in merged values as hoped.

An easy way to generate the directives is:

```
fc-list -f 'Fontpath "%{file|dirname}"\n' : | sort -u
```

This uses the formatted output (`-f`) of `fc-list` to create the required configuration lines, `%{file}` is the filename of each font, `|dirname` is a *filter* that outputs the directory name (exactly like the `dirname` shell command), then `sort -u` for unique paths. You may wish to reorder the paths if you have many fonts, if you have bitmap versions you can do something like this to reorder:

```
fc-list -f '    Fontpath "%{file|dirname}"\n' :scalable=true | sort -u
fc-list -f '    Fontpath "%{file|dirname}"\n' :scalable=false | sort -u
```

You can paste that output as required - or - as an example of all the steps (as root)

```
# extract Files section from xorg.conf to a separate conf
sed -n '/^Section..Files/,/^EndSection/p' \
  < /etc/X11/xorg.conf > /etc/x11/xorg.conf.d/10-section-files.conf
# comment out Files section in xorg.conf
sed -i.bak '/^Section..Files/,/^EndSection/ s/^/#/' /etc/X11/xorg.conf

# paths for scalable fonts
( echo 'Section "Files"'; 
  fc-list -f '    Fontpath "%{file|dirname}"\n' :scalable=true | sort -u;
  echo 'EndSection' ) > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-fontpath.conf

# paths for non-scalable fonts
( echo 'Section "Files"'; 
  fc-list -f '    Fontpath "%{file|dirname}"\n' :scalable=False | sort -u;
  echo 'EndSection' ) > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-fontpath-fixed.conf
```

Reorder and remove duplicates if required, and restart X.

For completeness, you can also modify the font paths on the fly with `xset`, e.g.

```
xset +fp /usr/local/share/fonts/TTF
```

Check the current paths with `xset q`. You could trivially modify this  to add such commands to your `.xinitrc` script so font paths persist independently of any subsequent X configuration changes, and save restarting X too.